# PHP add data from sqldb to cookies

Tags: php, sql, database, cookies

I have managed to make a cookie with the username from the login form, but how can I add the user id from the db query into the cookie too ?

This is what I've got now

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';


// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

setcookie("user", $myusername, time()+3600);
header("location:index.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this .

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'connection.php';


// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
$users = mysql_fetch_array($result);
# pass the user ID column name as array key of `$users`
setcookie("userID", $users['user_id'], time()+3600);
header("location:index.php");
 ob_clean();
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: for both username and userid I would need two cookies right ?

Comment: yap :P if you want to save both then you need two cookies

Answer (score 0):

it's easier to do it with `$_SESSION`.
Add `session_start();` on the top of every page you want to use the session variables on. After that, you can set and get session variables like with any normal array. example:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
$_SESSION['userId'] = 5;
?>
```

on a different page:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['loggedIn']; //will contain true
echo $_SESSION['userId'] = 5; //will contain 5
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
// Assuming that the column name in the DB is user_id then you can get the user_id using : $Rows['user_id']
// so you can store the cookie in this way:
setcookie("user_id", $Rows['user_id'], time()+3600);
```